# webroot wont detect root path on Let's Encrypt certification creation

Tags: ssl, nginx, encryption, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to install Let's Encrypt on a Bigbluebutton installation over Nginx. I add this to my SSL server block:

```
location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
        }
```

Then it comes the funny part.

My website `root` is configured in `/var/www/bigbluebutton-default/`, so I start the installation process with:

```
certbot-auto certonly -a webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/bigbluebutton-default
```

Then I get this:

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Please enter in your domain name(s) (comma and/or space separated)  (Enter 'c'
to cancel):myurl.com
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for myurl.com
Using the webroot path /var/www/bigbluebutton-default for all unmatched domains.
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Failed authorization procedure. myurl.com (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://myurl.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/QbxahZ29q3KrJDeT6QTNqlw57_CwO-W6AmfLDSyHlRQ: "<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>"

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: myurl.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://myurl.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/QbxahZ29q3KrJDeT6QTNqlw57_CwO-W6AmfLDSyHlRQ:
   "<html>
   <head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
   <body bgcolor="white">
   <center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
   <hr><center>"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

I checked all my DNS settings and everything is ok. So I check my `bigbluebutton-error.log` and this is what I've got:

```
2017/01/27 14:29:44 [error] 1213#0: *33 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/.well-known/acme-challenge/QbxahZ29q3KrJDeT6QTNqlw57_CwO-W6AmfLDSyHlRQ" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.28.105.8, server: myurl.com, request: "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/QbxahZ29q3KrJDeT6QTNqlw57_CwO-W6AmfLDSyHlRQ HTTP/1.1", host: "myurl.com"
```

As you can see its targeting a `/usr/share/nginx/html/` which I don't have it declared in any place.

Comment: Are you sure your `root` directive is in scope? It looks like the default root (when no `root` directive has been specified).

Answer (score 0):

Make a file http://myurl.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/test.txt, then go to your console and get it with wget. If you get an 404 double check your DNS settings, if you are using external DNS don't miss to add your domain to **hosts** file. But if you got an 403, it means that a Nginx configuration is blocking ".file" (override), because is a common practice (check your whole configuration file).

Another method is the --manual parameter:

```
... certonly --manual -d example.com
```

It will make a challenge file and you must upload it manually.